# Scala import problems - error: not found: value

Tags: scala, import, package

I'm a Haskeller looking into Scala. I'm meeting frustration not with code, but with imports/packages.

I have two files, `Test.scala` and `Lists.scala`.

```
// Lists.scala
package problems

object Lists {
  def last(list: List[Any]): Option[Any] = list match {
    case Nil      => None
    case x :: Nil => Some(x)
    case _ :: xs  => last(xs)
  }
}
```

And:

```
// Test.scala
import problems._

object Test extends App {
  println("Starting tests...")
  println(last(List(1,2,3,4,5)))
}
```

`Test.scala` does not compile. Running `scalac Test.scala Lists.scala` yields:

```
Test.scala:5: error: not found: value last
  println(last(List(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Yet rewriting `last` as `Lists.last` makes it succeed. Doesn't that defeat the point of the `import problems._` wildcard? I notice that math functions can be written without a preceeding `math.` by doing `import math._`. Why won't this work for my files as well?

Real aim: I just want to be able to make a package, then easily test its functions with `println` in another file. What's the best way to do that? Can I not do away with the `object {...}` in `Test.scala` and just run it with `scala`, forgoing the compilation process?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Doesn't that defeat the point of the import problems._ wildcard?

No, it does not. By using the wildcard you're bringing all the classes/objects in that package into the scope, but **not their contents**.

> I notice that math functions can be written without a preceding `math.` by doing `import math._` Why won't this work for my files as well?

It will work, but you need a proper import: `import problems.Lists._`. Otherwise you can place your functions into a [package object](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html).